# Any modules for editing files in the browser?

Tags: files

I need a way to edit any file in my template directory, but not through a local editor and then by using FTP, but by using my browser. I was wondering if anybody knows a Drupal module or another product that lets you do this.

Answer (score 2):

Well, [elFinder](http://drupal.org/project/elfinder), and [this page](http://drupal.org/node/265416) may help you. At least elFinder supports inline file diting. Good luck!